# eCharts bar3D one color by step yAxis3D

Tags: javascript, echarts

I try without success to define a single color for each step yAxis3D 
whatever the value. I took the following example: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar3d-punch-card&gl=1

```
series: [{

        type: 'bar3D',
        data: data.map(function (item) {
            return {
                value: [item[1], item[0], item[2]],
                itemStyle: { color: 'green' } // not working
            }
        }),

        itemStyle: {
            opacity: 1,
        },

        label: {
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 16,
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        },

        emphasis: {
            label: {

                normal: {
                    show: false,
                },
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: '#900'
                }
            },

        }
    }]
```